# Custom dash in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem with my bibliography. I took a look but I couldn't find any solution. The thing is: When citing something with a page range, I use a short dash, but when `biblatex` sorts a page range in my bib entry the dash is long even if in my bibentry I typed if short. So at the end I get two dashes, a short one made by me and a long one made by `biblatex`. I would like to have just short dashes.

Any ideas?

Here's the MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}


@article{Stu:Pat,
    Author = {Despina Stratoydaki-White},
    Date-Added = {2015-11-18 12:39:01 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-11-18 12:40:01 +0000},
    Journal = {The Greek Orthodox Theologica Review},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {195-205},
    Title = {Patriarch Photios - A Christian Humanist},
    Volume = {25},
    Year = {1980}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}   %openany
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

%%% bibliografia
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,                    
            backend=biber,                  
        ]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{archivio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[197-198]{Stu:Pat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Italian localisation files for `biblatex` define the range separator used for pages and year ranges (`\bibrangedash`) to be an en-dash (a long dash). This makes me think that it would be more usual to use long en-dashes for both page ranges.

Biber normalises the page ranges given in the `pages` field and replaces all `-`s with `\bibrangedash`, but prior to version 3.11 of `biblatex` page ranges in the `postnote` were not normalised (they are not passed to Biber and handled by `biblatex` alone). This changed in `biblatex` 3.11, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/293. `biblatex` is now able to normalise page ranges on its own and will do so for `postnote`. Then your MWE will come out with en-dashes in both page ranges.

If you always want short dashes, go with

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{italian}{%
  \protected\def\bibrangedash{%
    -\penalty\hyphenpenalty}}
```

This will work for present and future versions of `biblatex`.
The definition of `\bibrangedash` is specific to the used language, that's why you need `\DefineBibliographyExtras{italian}`.