# Prevent replacing a dash by \bibrangedash in a biblatex entry

Tags: biblatex

I have an entry in my bibliography that has a number looking like `number = {D-810}`.

Biblatex replaces dashes in the number field by `\bibrangedash`; for normal number ranges like `number = {2-3}` it is completely correct, but `D-810` is *not* a range, but a special kind of number, and should be displayed with a short dash.

I've found tips how to redefine the style of all occurrences of `\bibrangedash`, e.g. [Custom dash in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417547/custom-dash-in-biblatex), but what I need is to prevent a dash from being replaced by `\bibrangedash` just in a single entry.

How could I achieve this?

MWE for the style I need:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@TECHREPORT{c1,
  author      = {Author, A.},
  title       = {Some title},
  institution = {Inst. 1},
  year        = {2000},
  type        = {Preprint},
  number      = {D-810},
  address     = {Some city},
  pagetotal   = {10},
  langid      = {english},
}
@TECHREPORT{c2,
  author      = {Author, B.},
  title       = {Another title},
  institution = {Inst. 2},
  year        = {2000},
  type        = {Preprint},
  number      = {2-3},
  address     = {Some city},
  pagetotal   = {10},
  langid      = {english},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric]{biblatex} % from package biblatex-gost
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Citations:~\cite{c1,c2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did a few tests with the standard styles and `biblatex` 3.11/Biber 2.11 and I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe there. A `-` in the `number` field is not modified. Please consider adding a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to your question. That MWE needs to tell show us one `.bib` entry *and* the `biblatex` style you use as well as other settings related to the bibliography.

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: If you use `D\symbol{45}810` then you get a hyphen: I understand it's suboptimal, so this can't be an answer. From the `bbl` file, I gather that Biber knows it's not a range, because it writes `\range{number}{-1}`, but it replaces `-` with `\bibrangedash` nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks very much, @egreg, a `\symbol{45}` solution seems completely fine to me for those rare cases when the `number` field is not a range; actually I have only two such entries in my 200+ bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-gost` defines the `number` field to be a 'range field'. The standard styles on the other hand define the field as 'integer' and will treat it as a 'literal' field from version 3.12 onwards. This issue does not occur with the standard styles, it only comes to light in `biblatex-gost`.

The deciding feature of a range field is that all sort of dashes get normalised to `\bibrangedash` automatically. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to break out of this normalisation (there is one exception in ranges like `x-000--y-999` only the `--` is replaced by `\bibrangedash`, the single `-`s are left alone, but that can't help you here) if you want to keep using `-`.

A simple, but sadly neither elegant nor particularly portable work-around is

```
\newcommand*{\norangehyphen}{-}
```

and then

```
@TECHREPORT{c1,
  author      = {Author, A.},
  title       = {Some title},
  institution = {Inst. 1},
  year        = {2000},
  type        = {Preprint},
  number      = {D\norangehyphen810},
  address     = {Some city},
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `\symbol{45}` as egreg suggests in the comments.

Before reading the code of `biblatex-gost` I would have suggested to ask its author to stop treating `number` as a range field, but after are more thorough look it has become clear that quite a bit of code actually relies on `number` being a range field, so that is not an option.

In other `biblatex` contexts it would be enough to 'protect' the `-` from being converted to `\bibrangedash` by shielding with with curly braces

```
  number      = {D{-}810},
```

this does not work for Biber-detected ranges, however. But if you think this is an important feature, you may consider adding this as a feature request at the Biber bugtracker https://github.com/plk/biber/issues

Comment: Thank you very much, @moewe! Actually, both solutions, `\newcommand*{\norangehyphen}{-}` and `\symbol{45}`, work well. Maybe they are not quite elegant, but not-a-range numbers containing `-` are actually very rare and definitely non-standard, so I am personally completely fine with these workarounds. Maybe I'd think about contacting the developers of biblatex-gost and asking them to add some standard way to handle such cases.

Comment: @DmitryTsirkov Fortunately, numbers like `D-810` are rare, but similar things seem to be on the rise. And people in general often expect this to work. You can try to ask the `biblatex-gost` developer (no plural, I believe), but as I explained it may be too late at that stage, so he may well direct you to Biber. But it is probably a good idea to make him aware of the problem: https://github.com/odomanov/biblatex-gost/issues