# Change the format for bibliography entries and babel issues

Tags: biblatex, babel

I would like to change the format in which bibliography entries appear. I have tried redefining macros but since I am also using Estonian with the `babel` package, it overwrites my definitions. Currently, this entry

```
@inproceedings{gan,
  author    = {Ian Goodfellow and Jean Pouget-Abadie and Mehdi Mirza and Bing Xu and David Warde-Farley and Sherjil Ozair and Aaron Courville Yoshua Bengio},
  title     = {Generative adversarial networks},
  booktitle = {{NIPS}},
  editor    = {Z. Ghahramani and M. Welling and C. Cortes and N. D. Lawrence and K. Q. Weinberger},
  pages     = {2672--2680},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  location  = {New York},
}
```

appears as

> Ian Goodfellow, Jean Pouget­-Abadie, Mehdi Mirza, Bing Xu, David Warde­-Farley, Sherjil Ozair ja Aaron Courville Yoshua Bengio. Generative adversarial networks. Teoses: *NIPS*. Toim. Z. Ghahramani, M. Welling, C. Cortes, N. D. Lawrence ja K. Q. Weinberger. New York: Curran Associates, Inc., 2014, lk. 2672–2680.

but would like it to appear as

> Ian Goodfellow, Jean Pouget­-Abadie, Mehdi Mirza, Bing Xu, David Warde­-Farley, Sherjil Ozair ja Aaron Courville Yoshua Bengio 2014. Generative adversarial networks. - *NIPS*. Ed. Z. Ghahramani, M. Welling, C. Cortes, N. D. Lawrence ja K. Q. Weinberger. New York: Curran Associates, Inc., pp. 2672–2680

The `booktitle` should be in italics.

For example, I have tried redefining the `in:` bibmacro

```
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space\textendash\space}}
```

but due to `babel` the output does not change.

**EDIT, added MWEB**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[estonian .notilde]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{} % Doesn't print anything in the label
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt} % Eliminates the spacing before the entries
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} % No quotation marks

% This redefinition doesn't change anything due to babel
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space\textendash\space}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{gan,
  author    = {Ian Goodfellow and Jean Pouget-Abadie and Mehdi Mirza and Bing Xu and David Warde-Farley and Sherjil Ozair and Aaron Courville Yoshua Bengio},
  title     = {Generative adversarial networks},
  booktitle = {{NIPS}},
  editor    = {Z. Ghahramani and M. Welling and C. Cortes and N. D. Lawrence and K. Q. Weinberger},
  pages     = {2672--2680},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \parencite{gan}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows what you tried so far? Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`estonain.lbx` redefines the bibmacro `in:` in `\DeclareBibliographyExtras` (in a way that goes against the idea of separating style and localisation, but sometimes this was seen as necessary; a similar effect can be seen in English [How to get rid of the "Oxford comma" in a listing of three or more authors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415938/35864), French: [Keep lowercase in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864), Italian: [Custom dash in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417547/35864), a much more extreme example is `magyar.lbx`). If you want to overwrite that definition, you need to make it within `\DefineBibliographyExtras{estonian}`.

I also changed some bibstrings according to your example entry (I don't know any Estonian, I just took the English strings).

Note that I switched to a full `authoryear` style with `style=authoryear,` instead of faking it with `citestyle=authoryear,` and suppressing the numeric labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[estonian.notilde]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{estonian}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space\textendash\space}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{estonian}{
  editor           = {ed\adddot},
  editors          = {ed\adddot},
  byeditor         = {ed\adddot},
  page             = {p\adddot},
  pages            = {pp\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{gan,
  author    = {Ian Goodfellow and Jean Pouget-Abadie and Mehdi Mirza
               and Bing Xu and David Warde-Farley and Sherjil Ozair
               and Aaron Courville Yoshua Bengio},
  title     = {Generative adversarial networks},
  booktitle = {{NIPS}},
  editor    = {Z. Ghahramani and M. Welling and C. Cortes
               and N. D. Lawrence and K. Q. Weinberger},
  pages     = {2672--2680},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \parencite{gan}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goodfellow, Ian, Jean Pouget-Abadie, Mehdi Mirza, Bing Xu, David Warde-Farley, Sherjil Ozair ja Aaron Courville Yoshua Bengio (2014). Generative adversarial networks. – NIPS. Ed. Z. Ghahramani, M. Welling, C. Cortes, N. D. Lawrence ja K. Q. Weinberger. New York: Curran Associates, Inc., pp. 2672–2680.]

Comment: Thank you! But do you also know how to remove the small indentation after the first line in the bibliography?

Comment: @jazzboi Yes, that would be `\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}`, but then I'd strongly suggest to set `\bibitemsep` to a non-zero value (i.e. at least `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}` if not `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{2\itemsep}` or something even larger).